# Convert binary stream of numbers into all 1's

Tags: algorithm

I have string of binary chars such as "10101". I need to convert it into all 1's. The way I need to convert it is using method below which reverse the string from 0 to j and then flips each chars from 0 to j index.

```
void ReverseAndFlip(string &str, int j)
{
    int i=0;
    while(i<j)
    {
        char temp = str[i];
        str[i++]=str[j];
        str[j--]=temp;
    }
    for(int k=0;k<=j;k++)
    {
        if(str[k]=='0')
            str[k] = '1';
        else
            str[k]=='0';
    }
}
```

I need to determine the minimum number of calls needed to ReverseAndFlip function to convert the binary string into all 1's.

Comment: What's correct, the program or it's explanation? The two seem to diverge.

Comment: All are asking the same ques today why?,is this because this is the 2nd ques of the Code Jam

Answer (score 0):

I think that an algorithm just to *solve* the problem isn't trivial, so I'll post one here, although admittedly it doesn't completely answer the question. The minimality of what I'm about to show has yet to be determined, but I can guarantee we need at most n steps for a binary word of length n.

The trick here is that we can really only manipulate bits on the front of the word, not the back. This implies we should do some "front" grouping. So, my algorithm is as follows. Find the largest substring of a consistent digit (either 1 or 0) starting at the front of the word. Then flip all these bits (note that flipping and reversing is the same as flipping if they're all the same). Then, repeat the process until we have all 1s.

Example:

```
 |      j=1   ||     j=2   |||    j=3   ||||   j=4
"10101" ---> "00101" ---> "11101" ---> "00001" ---> "11111"
```

Another Example:

```
 ||          j=1   ||||        j=2   |||||       j=3   |||||| 
"0011010111" ---> "1111010111" ---> "0000010111" ---> "1111110111" 

j=4   |||||||     j=5
---> "0000000111" ---> "1111111111"
```

So, this algorithm runs in as many "flips" that we have, plus one if the word ends with 0. So, "10101" has 4 flips ("1x0x1x0x1"), since every single bit flips, and we end with one. Thus, 4 total flips. "0011010111" has 5 flips ("00x11x0x1x0x111"). If the number has a 0 on the end, we have a bonus flip. For example, "11001010" has ("11x00x1x0x1x0x") 6 flips, because the last digit is 0, so the last step just flips all 0s to 1s. Like so:

```
         j=1           j=2           j=3           j=4
11001010 ---> 00001010 ---> 11111010 ---> 00000010 ---> 11111110

j=5           j=6
---> 00000000 ---> 11111111
```

Now to show why this is/is not the minimal number of flips. Showing it's not minimal is easy, just find a way to flip one of my examples (or any other example) faster than the algorithm above.